# sudo command doesn't autocomplete anymore on files

Tags: bash, auto-completion

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I don't know what I did, everything was working fine, but since today my bash doesn't autocomplete anymore when I use sudo.
I can use the autocompletion as normal user, I can use autocompletion as root, I can use autocompletion for directories with sudo, but I can't use autocompletion for files if I use sudo.

If I write:

```
$sudo vim /etc/ssm[TAB]
```

it will autocomplete to:

```
$sudo vim /etc/ssmtp/
```

but then if I hit [TAB] again, even twice like I was used to list the files in the directory, nothing happens.
I already checked and I have the autocompletion enabled in the user .bashrc and also in /etc/bash.bashrc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try firstly **reinstalling the bash-completion** package with:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion

Then **backing up your .bashrc file**:

> mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak

Finally, **replace your .bashrc file** with the default from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` by using:

> cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/

This will ensure the following 'complete' config is restored within the file:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Also check both the containing folder and file permissions of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` - ownership should be root:root and yourusername:yourusergroup respectively.  The permissions of the files are important as the shell only uses your own privilege level to auto-complete commands. Elevated permissions such as when sudo is invoked are only used after the command is committed by pressing enter.

Comment: Done. The problem is still there.

Comment: It still appears you have some problem with bash-completion. Maybe try uninstalling with the 'purge' option. As a workaround and test, you can use the native completion of bash with alt + / rather than tab, which should complete file names for you.

Comment: I already purged and reinstalled. The strange thing is that I can use autocomplete as user and as root, but not as user using sudo.

Comment: @effemmeffe I have updated the answer to include your solution to give a fully rounded answer.

Comment: I think that you could also add the comment from user596137 about the fact that sudo doesn't autocomplete because it uses user permission before pressing enter.

Comment: Added, credit to @user596137

Comment: Reinstalling bash-completion worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say the current step order "*first reinstall bash-completion, then start anew with your `~/.bashrc`*" is upside-down/overkill for most people stumbling upon *this* question when searching for a solution to problems with bash autocompletion in the context of `sudo` or when using bash in the context of user `root`. Instead, probably most often all is required is uncommenting/activating the bash-completion snippet in file `/etc/bash.bashrc`, just as it is suggested in the comment in  `/etc/skel/.bashrc` / `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
complete -cf sudo
```

to your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`. Autocompletion will work on next login

Comment: For commands like `sudo su` this does not add username tab completing, so not what I was looking for at least

Answer (score 2):

I find out that the problem wasn't about autocomplete, but just a matter of permissions. 
The folder is own by root:mail instead of root:root as most of the directories in /etc and my user wasn't in the mail group. 
Once I added the user to the right group it worked. 
I just don't understand why the command with sudo in front of it didn't superseded the group...

Comment: Because elevated permission from sudo start to work only after you press enter, before pressing enter shell uses just your permissions.